# Validating a value with an array, Laravel validation. value must be one in the array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to validate a value by checking the value is in an array, this is what I have so far:

```
$agency_names = Session::get('config.agency-names');
$request->validate([
   'agency-name' => 'required|array:' . $agency_names . ''
]);
```

$agency_names (output):

```
0:
  AgencyID: "A1169"
  AgencyName: "19 London"
  AgencyType: "Agency Plus"

1:
  AgencyID: "A1095"
  AgencyName: "Abbeville Nannies"
  AgencyType: "Affiliate"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated code:

```
$agencies = Session::get('config.agency-names');

$names = array_map(fn($agency_data): string => $agency_data->AgencyName, $agencies);

$request->validate(['agency-name' => 'required', Rule::in($names)]);
```

Updated code (resolved)

```
$agencies = Session::get('config.agency-names');
    $agency_names = array();
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($agencies['Agencies']); $x++) {
        $name = $agencies['Agencies'][$x]["AgencyName"];
        array_push($agency_names, $name);
    }

$request->validate(['agency-name' => ['required_if:referral,no', Rule::in($agency_names)]]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [Laravel validaion rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in), specifically the `in` rule.

Assuming `$agency_names` is an array, you can do this:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

...

$request->validate([
  'agency-name' => [
    'required',
    Rule::in($agency_names),
]);
```

PS. Seeing the structure of your `$agency_names` array, you should map it first with `$names = array_map(fn($agency_data): string => $agency_data->AgencyName, $agency_names);`.
I also suggest renaming `$agency_names` to `$agencies`, because the variable name is misleading.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting this error now

'ErrorException
Array to string conversion'

I have tried using the implode method tho convert the array to a string but still get the same error.

Comment: so.. `agency-name` is an array? can you give an example of what it might contain? and what is `$agency_names`?

Comment: I have added the JSON for the $agency_names array. I tried looping the array and pushing the 'AgencyName' value into a separate array to use instead.

Comment: please add it to your original post, not to my answer.

Comment: and i saw your edit added an example for `$agency_names` but you still didn't answer what is the type of the incoming `agency-name` and an example for that. in my answer i assumed it to be a string, like the variable name suggests, but i think you might be using an array, hence the error.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to validate an input value using a nested array. the value for the 'AgencyNames' is a string value.

Comment: I have been looking in the Laravel documentation for the best validation rule. Do I have to convert the array or refactor it?

Comment: @JEDBOYLE i edited my answer to account for your array structure.

Comment: Thank you, although I get a new error now:

'Trying to get property 'AgencyName' of non-object'

Comment: I have added the refactored code to my original post

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. The response array was nested and I had to create a new array that just contained the names. I have added the new code at the bottom of my original question.